# standard UML-to-code-mapping(Forward Engineering)?

Tags: uml, standards, modeling, specifications

I wonder if there is widely accepted standard for the UML(unified modelling language)-to-code-mapping(Forward Engineering)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one translation from UML to code.  That's due to a number of reasons, including:

- What bits of UML you use and how.  UML is a large language.  Historically it has been much stronger on the static side of things (classes, associations, packages) than on the dynamics.  It's only comparatively recently that UML has acquired the action semantics required for executable models.  And in comparison to the more established static elements, these newer parts aren't (yet) well supported.  This has arguably been a major reason why canonical MDA transforms haven't become more widespread.
- It's possible to target different programming languages.  Translation to 3rd generation OO languages is probably most popular.  But it's also possible to translate into other languages: C is a popular choice, especially in the embedded world.
- Different translation rules are possible depending on the needs of the particular environment.

That said, there are some popular idioms.  For example:

1. UML packages, classes and attributes are often mapped directly to their OO 3GL counterparts.  In fact, many UML models are just graphical renditions of 3GL OO code.
2. UML relationships are usually split in two, with pointers/references stored in each relationship end.
3. There are 3 common models for translating UML state models (or more generally any state model): nested switches, state tables and the state pattern.

Action Languages are too new/not well enough supported for there to be canonical mappings.  That said, the specs pretty closely mirror typical 3GL constructs: if/then/else control statements, assignments, etc.  The semantic gap between model and target is therefore pretty small - so translation should be reasonably straightforward.

hth.

Comment: Hi @sfinnie ! What do you mean by "UML is stronger on the static side of things  than on the dynamics"?

Comment: #Responding to What bits of UML you use 
Suppose I will use class diagram , activity and sequence diagram .
with regards to how 
I will use them according to OMG specification.so what is the problem in this point(in your first reason)?
#IMHO, UML is not a large language ,I agree with you that UML has a large spec document  #I think most of the work would be put on translation rules simply because UML is not well formalized and subject to different interpretation .Do you think so???

Comment: @user2019510: #1: by "stronger on the static side" I mean the UML structural concepts - Classes, Attributes, Associations, Packages etc. - are more generally accepted, used and implemented. #2: yes, activity/sequence diags can be translated directly into code.  But they can't capture all actions, hence the need for the action semantics.  So you'll need to decide how to handle those. #3: I agree UML suffers from historically not having been well formalised - at least not from an executable/translatable model perspective. hth.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no standard mapping from UML to code. Although UML can be used to "draw" code, it has been designed to work at an "upper" level (at the business level). So there is not one way to generate code from an UML model but almost as many as systems (and to many languages).

Comment: thank you @Xaelis
What about automatic transformations in MDA?
Does that transformation not subjects to standard steps?

Comment: MDA define a process at a very high level. First making a PIM (Platform Independent Model) i.e. a model with only business logic no technical choices. Then transform the PIM into a PSM (Platform Specific Model) i.e. a model "showing" how to implement the business logic on a specific technical platform. Then generate code from this PSM. This is the MDA general idea.